# Mysql not using index on group by and order by

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing

I have table users with following columns.

id, name, updated_at

Query with explain plan

```
mysql> explain select * from users group by users.id order by users.updated_at desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 190551 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Created a new index

```
create index test_id_updated_at on users (id, updated_at);
```

After creating a new index still getting the same result with explain plan.

```
mysql> explain select * from users group by users.id order by users.updated_at desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 190551 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

After forcing a new index in query, still getting same result.

I don't understand why it says 'Using filesort' after creating a new index.

Comment: The query uses GROUP BY. Why? Also, personally, I prefer to use \G when executing EXPLAINs for pasting here. I find it easier to read. (Along with the provision of proper DDLs of course)

Comment: Please include the complete definition of table `users`.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your cenario, and mysql used the index:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM test_index GROUP BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 393520 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE INDEX index1 ON test_index(id, updated_at);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.85 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM test_index GROUP BY id ORDER BY updated_at DESC;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_index | index | NULL          | index1 | 12      | NULL | 393520 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe your mysql version? Tested this on 5.5.

It's hard to optimize this query (remove the using filesort and temporary) without knowing the full table structure and what you want to retrieve with this (specify the fields instead of "*")